# Auto Reload of report on parameter selection in Reporting Services

Tags: reportingservices-2005

In Microsoft Reporting Services 2005, I would like my report to refresh every time the value of a sql parameter is changed by the viewer.

How can that be done ? More generally, how can I force refresh on certain actions (typically, a click on a button ) ?

Comment: By 'viewer' do you mean the Report Viewer control, or do you mean someone actually viewing the report?

Answer (score 1):

I find that the best way to refresh a report is to do the following:

1. Do a ReportViewer.Reset()
2. Set the ReportDefinition on the ReportViewer control again.
3. Do a ReportViewer.RefreshReport()

You could write the above logic into a function, then call the function whenever a Event occurs.